# Replace DropDownList with auto-generated Buttons

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This DropDownList automatically populates with every report in my project. Select the one you want to launch, and it immediately launches.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Reports,
    new SelectList(Model.Reports, "ReportUrlText", "ReportNameText"), "",
    new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

[image]

How can I replace this with an automatically-generated list of Buttons or Hyperlinks? Such that the user can see all the available reports immediately, without needing to open a dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate on `Model.Reports` with a `foreach` loop, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   @foreach (var report in Model.Reports)
   {
      <a href="@report.ReportUrlText" class="button">@report.ReportNameText</a>
   }
</div>
```